# sorl thumbnail not working

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm having an issue with getting sorl thumbnail to work.

I've added `sorl.thumbnail` to INSTALLED_APPS and in the template at the top

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load thumbnail %}
```

I've also checked if pillow is properly installed.

Tested it

```
<span class="test">{% thumbnail "http://animal-dream.com/data_images/cow/cow5.jpg" "1300x700" as image %}{{ image.url }}{% endthumbnail %}</span>
```

Did the above just to see the output.
When I check

```
$('.test')
<span class=​"test">​</span>​
```

Comment: I'm having issues as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep migrate it with this commands

> ./manage.py makemigrations thumbnail
>
> ./manage.py migrate

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is you need to run migrate so it creates tables first otherwise thumbnail tag wont work.